# How to Count number of working days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 with data below:

```
user ,number of request, date number of request

user1, ID1139151, 2017-03-15 13:10:01.000

user1, ID1139152, 2017-03-13 14:31:05.000

user2, ID1139153, 2017-03-16 10:38:08.000

user2, ID1139154, 2017-03-16 09:26:04.000

user2, ID1139155, 2017-03-17 18:09:15.000

user2, ID1139156, 2017-03-17 20:14:29.000

user2, ID1139157, 2017-03-28 11:18:18.000
```

Help me to find a summ of days by every user with help of SQL query.

```
Result:

user, date number of request

user1, 2

user2, 3
```

**Script to create data :**

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable (

   [user] varchar(50) NOT NULL,

   [number of request] varchar(15) NOT NULL,

   [date_number_of_request] datetime NOT NULL,     )


INSERT INTO Mytable  

VALUES 

('user1','ID1139151','2017-03-15 13:10:01.000'),

('user1','ID1139152','2017-03-13 14:31:05.000'),

('user2','ID1139153','2017-03-16 10:38:08.000'),

('user2','ID1139154','2017-03-16 09:26:04.000'),

('user2','ID1139155','2017-03-17 18:09:15.000'),

('user2','ID1139156','2017-03-17 20:14:29.000'),

('user2','ID1139157','2017-03-28 11:18:18.000');
```

Comment: plus 1 for sample data,going forward try to  include any attempt you have tried as well

Comment: One approach is to add a [calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/) to your database.  This can be used to filter out non-working days.  Bank holidays cannot be identified unless you store them somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `count(distinct col)` and truncating the datetime to date with `dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, [date_number_of_request]), 0)`:

```
select [user]
    , DaysWithRequests = count(distinct 
        dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, [date_number_of_request]), 0)
        )
from mytable
group by [user]
```

Same query with using `convert(date,[date_number_of_request])`

```
select [user]
    , DaysWithRequests = count(distinct convert(date,[date_number_of_request]))
from mytable
group by [user]
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EMKMK22273

returns:

```
+-------+------------------+
| user  | DaysWithRequests |
+-------+------------------+
| user1 |                2 |
| user2 |                3 |
+-------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do something like this:

```
 SELECT users, COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(date_number_of_request AS date))
 FROM mytable 
 GROUP BY users
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want, for each user, a count of the number of different dates in the `date_number_of_request` column?

```
select user, count(distinct convert(date, date_number_of_request))
  from myTable
 group by user
```